# Angular 17 change detection, on detached / re-attached component not working

Tags: angular

**Initial Creation**

I have a viewContainer, where I initially use the function viewContainer.CreateComponent().instance, to create an instance of a 'child component' to.
Everything works fine.

**Dictionary Store**

I also save the instance as a value to a dictionary (in a service), against the key 'modalType'.

**Destroy Parent**

Then I destroy the parent component that holds the viewContainer, and with it goes the 'child component'.

**Opening Parent again**

When I open the parent component again (it's actually a filter modal, that displays a list, and the child component is the list, inside the modal), I check the dictionary to see if the instance of the child component exists (instead of creating a new instance). If it does, I use the following function to attach the 'child component' instance, back to the new viewContainer.

I use a dictionary store to keep the instances, so I can keep the 'state' of the 'child component', before it was destroyed (i.e. the list that may have had certain boxes ticked, before the parent was destroyed).

**Re-attaching child component**

I use this sort of function get the instance from the dictionary to attach to the viewContainer:

```
viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.appendChild(ModalService.modalInstances[modalType].elementRef.nativeElement)
```

**Problem**

Now everything works, (all the functions inside the 'child component' work), apart from one...

For some reason, the (change) event in the HMTL no longer fires. It does on the intially created instance, but not on the instance that I saved to the dictionary, and then recalled from it.

**Child component HTML**

Here is the html of the child component:

```
<ul>
  @for(item of uniqueItems; track $index){
    <li>
      <label for="checkbox-{{ $index }}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{ $index }}" [checked]="selectedItems.includes(item)" 
        #inputBox (change)="onItemChange(item, inputBox.checked, $event)" />
        <span>{{ item }}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Is this an unresolved Angular bug?
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38778

**UPDATE >>**

The entire problem I've found is caused by the parent viewContainer getting destroyed and re-created. Because my dictionary's are actually passed by reference, when the parent's viewContainer get's destroyed, the .hostview property of the child component in the dictionary also gets detroyed too (I didn't notice, as I was paying attention to my .instance property, that had my state values, which were still there in the child component in the dictionary)

I then tried creating a new component, using viewComponent.createComponent, to repair the .hostView element, and then pulling in the .instance property from the dictionary, that was still in tact, re-saving that back to the dictionary, and then attaching this child component back to the new viewContainer from the parent. It half worked. Some html of the child component generated,  but I still couldn't the list, that relied on the uniqueItems property to generate a list (even though uniqueItems was still in tact, in the .instance) property.

I tried for a few more hours, and the only thing that worked was using AppRef.components.[0] - where the viewContainer, not being tied to a particular sub-component, never gets detroyed.

I'm sure there is a better way.... but that's would I could find so far.